# Detecting Circular References in Spreadsheetgear Workbook

Tags: spreadsheetgear

Has anyone discovered how to detect circular references in a Spreadsheetgear Workbook control or creating custom code to detect it?

There is no available Property in Spreadsheetgear, so i am hoping someone has built a workaround that they could share.